# Referencing assemblies or dll should be copied in deployment directory or not?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, class, dll

I wrote a C# class DLL for my Bluetooth LE app on Win10 with .Net Framework 4.8, but it doesn't seem to work as i expected.
On my developement PC (Win10 as well), where I wrote the DLL, the app works just fine, but when I Install my app on another PC, it doesn't.
My question here: Do I have to copy dependencies too, that I used to write the DLL with? Or what do I have to do, to make the magic work?

The Libraries im using:

```
using SDKTemplate;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous;
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, you need the dependencies accessible (very likely copied to the deployment directory).

Comment: If you are giving reference to any dependent dll it should be copied in deployment directory.

Comment: a dll surely is some **external** functionality that is not located within your current one. So how else do you expect that functionality to be referenced, if not by sharing the assembly on the target-computer also?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your extremely fast answers!! 
Im new to programming DLLs, so can you tell me where the deployment directory is and what i have to copy where on the target system?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure.You need to copy all the refrenced assemblies from where you invoke your program.If it is exe then in bin/release folder.

Comment: @Gagan I added a screenshot of the folder structure. But im really unsure what files I have to copy to the target machine to make it work. As it seems i have to install .Net framework at least. The Error im getting seems to be Bluetooth related as well. The Values can only be read once and i can't understand why. The DLL is for reading a Value over Bluetooth but the app doesnt update the value so it seemss the dll isnt working right.

Comment: @Static if the target machine is Windows 10 1903 or later (run `winver` to check), it has Framework 4.8 installed. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Static wait, the program is loading and not crashing? Why do you think it's a dependency problem?

Comment: @CoolBots because the Dll is the only new feature I implemented and the rest works fine. The Dll is about BLE functionality and the only issue is, that it doesn't work as it should on another machine. To me, it clearly seems to be a problem with the dependencies, because the target machine has the same specs as my test PC. Win10 for example. The only Difference seems to be not copied dependencies

Comment: @Static a missing dependency would cause a hard crash. Period. No alternatives. If your program is running, but not working as expected, something else is wrong.

Comment: Can you checked the new reference assemblies  in bin/release folder and when you deploy the same are present there.You can log(like console.log or any logging framework like log4net) something so that you will get to know the referenced assemblies are working or not

Comment: @Gagan I have copied what i have in my Debug folder to the target machine application Folder with my app in it. I still get the same error. For the logging: I dont know how to use console.log. I tried reading it up but im not sure how to use it. Do i  have to put it somewhere in my ccode or call it while my code is running??

Comment: @CoolBots But if the dependency that is missing is something Bluetooth LE related. Wouldn't it just hinder the correct execution of the DLL? Or do you think the issue is something directly connected to BluetoothLE?

Comment: @Static the issue is more likely to be a difference in BLE related setup, such as driver version, hardware revision, Windows update patch, etc. The way a DLL in .NET is loaded, it can't be missing if the program runs; it might be of older version, but highly unlikely, and eliminated by copying the entire bin folder.

Comment: @CoolBots I just installed a Microsoft app that read values via Bluetooth LE. It works just fine, so Im positive that the Issue must lie with my DLL. There must be missing something, but I have absolutely no idea what it is or how i can look it up. Googling the problem doesn't get any results. I will start a new, more specific question here, regarding Bluetooth LE.
Thanks for help anyway!! It helped me narrowing it down

Comment: @Static no worries, sorry we didn't resolve it. Btw  if the app is UWP, it can be security settings related to sideloading. One interesting item to try, if possible, install VS 2019 on the target machine, and debug the project there - you'll get much more meaningful data. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your app must be able to load all dependencies, as they are not part of your DLL. This includes the .NET Framework 4 8, which isn't a standard part of Windows 10, and must be installed separately / with your app, and any third-party libraries and packages.

*EDIT:* .NET Framework 4.8 is part of Windows 10 May 2019 update (version 1903); if your target computer is at least that version, it'll be sufficient to copy the contents of your `bin\Release` folder (or `bin\Debug`, if you're building in Debug Configuration) to the target machine.